# When npm packages can be installed duplicately?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I create a project which depends on a package 'A' and 'B', if the pakckage 'A' depends on 'B', I guess sometimes 'B' could be installed in the node_module folder of package 'A' not node_module folder of the project.

```
Project
   - node_modules
     - A
       - node_modules
         - B
     - B
```

However, as far as I see, this seems not occur anytime. I want to know what is the condition this can be occurred.

Comment: Read this issue: [Install multiple versions of a dependency](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of npm from version 3 and is explained here https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3.